# lightning:carousel error

Tags: lightning, lightning-development

I'm new to lightning and never used carousel component. My requirement is to display different images by querying from object level and upon clicking on the picture it will call another component and pass a value which will be used as an attribute of the 2nd component.Kindly help.. please find below component ..

### apex

public class imagecheckcontact{

```
@AuraEnabled 
public static List<contact> getcons(){
    return [Select Id,name,sankha__image__c from contact where id in ('00328000014LZcM', '00328000014LZjA')];
}
```

}

### component

```
<lightning:carousel >
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.conct}" var="con">
        <lightning:carouselImage width="500px" height="600px" src = "{!con.sankha__image__c}" 
                                 description = "First card description."  onclick="{c.navigate}"  header = "{!con.name}" 
                                 >
        </lightning:carouselImage>
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:carousel>
```

**JS**

---

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getcons"); 
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                var retrunRes = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.conct" ,retrunRes );
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    navigate:function(component, event, helper) {
            var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
        evt.setParams({
            componentDef : "c:Helloworld",
            componentAttributes: {
                contactName : component.get("v.contact.Name")
            }
        });
        evt.fire();
    }

})
```

Comment: We need a bit more than "it's not working, please fix." Please [edit] your question to describe what's going on, any errors you may be seeing, the data type of `sankha__image__c`, which environment you're using (Lightning, Lightning Out, etc), and anything else you might think is relevant. Please read about [ask] and take the [tour] if you're unfamiliar with how SFSE works.

Comment: I'm not getting any error. Just the image is not getting displayed..It's coming as a broken image. I'm using lightning environment not lightning out. sankha__image__c data type is Rich Text Area(32768). Please let me know for any question

Comment: I do not understand what is the problem

Comment: Scenario :

 Retirving 4 product records including 3 fields.id, image(richtext field) and name.Displaying image in lightning carousal and also name as the header..Now I want to hold the product id , and pass it as param . Now i'm unable to hold the prod id value as lightning:carousal has no attribute neither aura:id , id or data-attriVal helping me to store the prod id value..Any workaround .

Answer (score 0):

You can not display images in carousel which are type of Rich text area. You have to break the image URL to required format and pass to src tag in lightning carousel.

src tag in lighting carousal accepts only this format
/sfsites/c/servlet/rtaImage?eid=a0B9E000004VP64&feoid=00N9E0000055I7z&refid=0EM9E000000HpxY

find below example how can you break URL to required format from apex send it in this format.

NOte: Even I am trying to capture ID from onclick of image. but no sucess please help me

```
Seminar_Catalog__c camp = [SELECT Id, Image__c FROM Seminar_Catalog__c where id ='a079E00000ALyU1' LIMIT 1];
System.debug('Rich field:');
System.debug(camp.Image__c);
String firstSubString = camp.Image__c.substringBetween('<img', 'img>');
System.debug('First substring: ' + firstSubString);
String secondSubString = firstSubString.substringBetween('src="', '"');
System.debug('Second substring: ' + secondSubString);
String link = secondSubString.replace('amp;', '');
System.debug('Link: ' + link);
```